# Label that is passed not appearing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to create a tableview where once a tableview cell is selected, it passes the name of the cell to a new view controller. When I run this and select a tableview cell, I am brought to another view controller, but the organization label is not there. How do I fix this?

Here is my code for the first view controller.

```
import UIKit

struct Organizations {
    var sectionTitle = String()
    var rowTitles = [String]()
}

class SearchOrganizationsViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var searchOrganizations: Organizations?
    var organizations = [
        Organizations(sectionTitle: "section 1", rowTitles: ["organization 1", "organization 2", "organization 3"]),
        Organizations(sectionTitle: "section 2", rowTitles: ["organization 1", "organization 2"]),
        Organizations(sectionTitle: "section 3", rowTitles: ["organization 1"]),
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    extension SearchOrganizationsViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "searchCell")
            cell?.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
            cell?.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 3
            if searching {
                cell?.textLabel?.text = self.searchArray[indexPath.section].rowTitles[indexPath.row]
            } else {
                cell?.textLabel?.text = self.organizations[indexPath.section].rowTitles[indexPath.row]
            }
            return cell!
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            selectedOrganizations = organizations[indexPath.row]
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "organizationDetailSegue", sender: self)
        }

        override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            if let destination = segue.destination as? OrganizationsDetailViewController {
                destination.organization = selectedOrganizations
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code for the second view controller.

```
import UIKit

class OrganizationsDetailViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var organizationNameLabel: UILabel!

    var organization: Organizations?

    var organizationName: String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        organizationNameLabel.text = organizationName
    }
}
```

Comment: Pleas show your `cellForRow` code. What error do you get?

Comment: I've updated my code to include my cellForRow and I do not receive any errors. Still there is nothing displayed on the new view controller.

Comment: In your second view controller, the label text display depends on `organizationName`. Well, none of your code ever sets that. So you see nothing. No surprise there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the selected `Organisation` by just storing it in a variable like this:

```swift
class SearchOrganizationsViewController: UIViewController {
    var selectedOrganisation: Organization?
    var organizations = [Organizations(sectionTitle: "section 1", rowTitles: ["organization 1", "organization 2", "organization 3"]),
            Organizations(sectionTitle: "section 2", rowTitles: ["organization 1", "organization 2"]),
            Organizations(sectionTitle: "section 3", rowTitles: ["organization 1"])
    ]
    //...
}

extension SearchOrganizationsViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedOrganizations = searching ? searchArray[indexPath.section] : organizations[indexPath.section]
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "organizationDetailSegue", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? OrganizationsDetailViewController {
            destination.organizationName = selectedOrganisation?. sectionTitle
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. When I run this, it doesn't show the text on the next view controller.

Comment: @Kar534 Check once again. I've updated my answer to show the name.

Answer (score 1):

Do this experiment. Change

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? OrganizationsDetailViewController {
        destination.organization = selectedOrganizations 
    }
}
```

To

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? OrganizationsDetailViewController {
        destination.organizationName = "Zampabalooie" 
    }
}
```

Do you see something now? If so, now change it again, to show the text you actually want to see.

Comment: Thanks. This works but how would I change my code to display the title from the tableview cell as the organizationName?